# How to get a Japanese spell-checker?

Tags: gnome, firefox, language-support, japanese, spell-checking

For all the other languages I have installed, a spell-checker is also installed for my various applications, most importantly probably Firefox. The spell-checkers usually come with the language packs, but can also be added manually in Firefox in the dictionaries list.

However for Japanese there is no such spell-checker seemingly anywhere. Now I understand that this is probably because it is hard to spell-check Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji together, but still it should be possible as it is with any other language. So I am wondering if there is a Japanese spell-checker I can install for at least Firefox? Though if it worked system-wide for other applications that would be good too.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 and Firefox 48.

Answer (score 1):

Because when I type Japanese, I need a special input method with engines, which understands my phonic input and display Hiragana words and suggests Kanji words for them.
 e.g. ibus-mozc, fcitx-mozc, ibus-anthy, uim-anthy (light weight)

So basically it couldn't be wrong. The system cannot suggest that we composed badly.